# Formating JSON object, From single quotation to double

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, replace

I'm using a data-set given to me and I'm trying to parse (Using Node) the JSON objects returned to me,

Turns out they are all using single quotations, and from my research JSON uses double.

> Example of a JSON object I get returned!

```
{
    'cast_id': 16,
    'character': 'Alexander Haig',
    'credit_id': '52fe43c59251416c7501d72d',
    'gender': 2,
    'id': 6280,
    'name': 'Powers Boothe',
    'order': 2,
    'profile_path': '/3nNL6AvMAYq0BmHKM79RnRZVq3i.jpg'
},
```

I've been using `str.replace()` to sort the objects out before `JSON.parse()` which was fine untill I found objects like this one

```
{
    'cast_id': 26,
    'character': '"Jack Jones"',
    'credit_id': '52fe43c59251416c7501d751',
    'gender': 2,
    'id': 6840,
    'name': 'Larry Hagman',
    'order': 16,
    'profile_path': '/40PVsGp5Wp5kbUhAefLHqjqbarc.jpg'
},
```

Notice the `'character': '"Jack Jones"',` This has been causing me all types of issues!

I there a library that will help parse this all for me?

Am I missing something?

## FYI:

I can't access each record as the JSON objects aren't stored separately instead, as a long string including up to 60 JSON objects.

[image: Screenshot of the dataset in the DB]

I currently have a function that helps parse the data:

```
function formatJSON(cast) {
    cast = cast.replace(/(\w) "(\w)/g, "$1 *$2");
    cast = cast.replace(/(\w)" /g, "$1* ");         
    cast = cast.replace(/': '/g, '": "');
    cast = cast.replace(/', '/g, '", "' );
    cast = cast.replace(/'},/g, '"},');
    cast = cast.replace(/': /g, '": ');
    cast = cast.replace(/, '/g, ', "');
    cast = cast.replace(/{'/g, '{"');
    cast = cast.replace(/: None}/g, ': "None"}');
    cast = cast.replace(/'}/g, '"}');
    return cast;
}
```

## Update

The data reportedly extracts nicely in python as a dictionary using `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: I'm not sure If I follow, I'm still kinda new to JS, however, I am aware of my horrific sight of a function and the fact it shouldn't exist.

Comment: Can't you ask for real JSON? People inventing they own formats usually get them wrong like `'"Jack'O Jones' ("Fighter"), the second"'` without any escaping...

Comment: Where is this data coming from? It looks like it's intended to be parsed using Python's `ast.literal_eval()`, not JSON. Are you sure you can't get them to provide valid JSON?

Comment: Since they're using a custom format, ask them how you're supposed to parse it. Maybe they have a library.

Comment: @Barmar The dataset is this https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset

Comment: @Barmar I found a discussion on the website, someone also mentioned the `ast.literal_eval()` but I don't use Python and really just want it as a JSON object, Looks like I'm going to have to learn another language

Answer (score -1):

By default, you don't need to replace a string which is wrapped by double quotes with the same string contains single quote. There is no difference between `'Jack Jones'` and `"Jack Jones"` since all of them are `string`.

In your case, you're trying to replace something like this example:

```js
var str = '\'Jack Jones\''.replace(/'/g, '"');

console.log('\'' + str + '\'');
```

---

So, if you want to wrap all of properties names and values by double quotes, you can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` like this:

```js
var cast = {
    'cast_id': 16,
    'character': 'Alexander Haig',
    'credit_id': '52fe43c59251416c7501d72d',
    'gender': 2,
    'id': 6280,
    'name': 'Powers Boothe',
    'order': 2,
    'profile_path': '/3nNL6AvMAYq0BmHKM79RnRZVq3i.jpg'
};

cast = JSON.stringify(cast);
cast = JSON.parse(cast);

console.log(cast);
```